# How to convert varchar to float for calculation in SQL Server 2008R

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm relatively new to programming with SQL Server and am trying to use a query that will convert a varchar field to a numeric field for calculations.  With the help of this website, I've gotten to the point where I thought I was accounting for any characters in the field, but I am still getting the "error converting data type varchar to float".  Here's the code (I hope it's not too long):

```
SELECT IRWD.Well_ID, IRWD. DepthtoProduct, IRWD.DepthtoWater,
IRWD.Product_in_Well, IRWD.OilWaterInterfaceElevation, WD.MeasuringPtElevation,
CASE
WHEN (LOWER(IRWD.DepthtoProduct) like '%nm%')   THEN 'NM'
WHEN (LOWER(IRWD.DepthtoWater) like '%nm%') THEN 'NM'
WHEN ISNUMERIC(IRWD.DepthtoProduct)= 1 and ISNUMERIC(IRWD.DepthtoWater)= 1
THEN CAST((CONVERT(float,WD.MeasuringPtElevation) - CONVERT(float,IRWD.DepthtoWater))AS float) 
ELSE 'NA'
END AS Product_in_Well

FROM InputRecoveryWellData AS IRWD
JOIN vw_ActiveWellData AS WD
ON IRWD.Well_ID = WD.RecoveryWell
AND IRWD.WellType = WD.WellType;
```

The premise is that there are wells that are measured regularly.  If there is product, it's depth is recorded, and the same for water in the wells.  If they aren't measured for some reason, an 'NM' is entered.  If there is a measurement, I need to calculate from them and if there isn't, it gets noted. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your case statement, In each CASE the query should return the same data type, here you are returning varchar in case 1 , 2 and 4 and returning a float value in 3rd case.

cast the value to varchar in 3rd case as well. And this should fix the issue.

Also if you are doing calculations it is best to convert it to DECIMAL rather than float as float is an approximate data type and you may get unexpected results.

```
CASE
WHEN (LOWER(IRWD.DepthtoProduct) like '%nm%')   THEN 'NM'
WHEN (LOWER(IRWD.DepthtoWater) like '%nm%')     THEN 'NM'
WHEN ISNUMERIC(IRWD.DepthtoProduct)= 1 and ISNUMERIC(IRWD.DepthtoWater)= 1
THEN CAST( CAST( WD.MeasuringPtElevation AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) 
          - CAST(IRWD.DepthtoWater AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) 
            AS VARCHAR(100))
ELSE 'NA'
END AS Product_in_Well
```

Comment: Thank you!  Of course when you explain it, it makes perfect sense.  I wound up changing the logic of the table so that the field is numeric.  Will also change to decimal for better control.  Thanks again.